# Load .text file in string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io

How can I load .txt file into string **array**?

```
private void FileLoader() {
    try {
        File file = new File("/some.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "Windows-1251");
            //Obviously, exception
            int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        morphBuffer[i] = sc.nextLine();
        i++;
            //Obviously, exception  
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found: " + e);
        return;
    }
}
```

There is an issue with array's length, because I don't know how long my array will be. 
Of course i saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file), but there is not an **array** of string. I need it, because I have to work with whole text, also **with** `null` strings.
How can I load a text file into string array?

Comment: [`java.util.ArrayList<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Java 7, [you can do it in a single line of code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29):

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines("/some.txt", Charset.forName("Cp1251"));
```

If you need your data in a string array rather than a `List<String>`, call `toArray(new Strinf[0])` on the result of the `readAllLines` method:

```
String[] allLines = Files.readAllLines("/some.txt", Charset.forName("Cp1251")).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: I can mistake, but I think `Charset.forName("Windiws-1251")`, rather than `Charset.forName("Cp1251")`. Or both will be right?

Comment: @linuxedhorse [You are right, that's two synonyms for the same encoding](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_Windows-1251_.28.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC_CP1251.29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection`  `ArrayList`

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(sc.nextLine());
    i++;
        //Obviously, exception  
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but how? I mean, how can I load a text file in ArrayList? And can I work with `ArrayList` using regex?

Comment: @linuxedhorse You can work with lists in (almost) the same way as with arrays. You can also convert lists to arrays if you prefer.

Comment: @linuxedhorse, where exactly are you using regex in your current code?

Comment: I'm using regex in method in class, where `FileLoader()` is, and I'm working with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use List

```
private void FileLoader() {
try {
    File file = new File("/some.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "Windows-1251");
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        mylist.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    sc.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found: " + e);
    return;
}
}
```